# UNIQUE CONSTRAINT FAILED : ZCLIPTABLE.Z_PK

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am getting this error when i am trying to fetch my clips from core data on my menu screen. on reaching menu screen it crashes

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"task=webapi.getAllClips"];
        [protocolTest  syncAllClips:post andEntityName:@"ClipTable"];
        }
```

here it crashes when i call syncAllClips method from other class below is the method code -

```
-(void)syncAllClips:(NSString*)postString andEntityName:(NSString*)entityName{

 NSLog(@"loop1");
 incline=0;
 [delegateInstance deleteCoreData:entityName];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegateInstance managedObjectContext];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 3 * 60.0;
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:[self postRequest:postString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
          else
        {
        if (data){

            NSString *_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *_escapedString = [_str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\'" withString:@"'"];
            //_escapedString = [_escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@"@@"];
            NSData *_escData = [_escapedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSDictionary *serverdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_escData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

           // NSArray *jsonDataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_escData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL]];
           // NSMutableArray *jsonDataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            NSMutableArray * jsonDataArray = (NSMutableArray *)[serverdata objectForKey:@"task"];

            //jsonDataArray =[serverdata objectForKey:@"task"];
        dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"serverdata is%@",serverdata);
             NSLog(@"jsonDataArray is%@",jsonDataArray);
           NSLog(@"datetime_value: %@", [serverdata objectForKey:@"datetime_value"]);
            NSLog(@"datetime_value: %@", [serverdata objectForKey:@"total_clips_count"]);
            //NSLog(@"serverdata :%@",serverdata);
            NSString *commonvideo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[serverdata objectForKey:@"video_clip_path"]];
            NSLog(@"commonvideo is%@",commonvideo);

            for(NSDictionary *dict in jsonDataArray)
            {
            incline++;


                // NSLog(@"serverdata :%@",[dict objectForKey:@"clip_image_path"]);
                // [datarara addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"clip_image_path"]];
                // Create a new device
                NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
                [newDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"clip_image_path"]] forKey:@"clip_image_path"];
                [newDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"clip_name"] forKey:@"clip_name"];
                [newDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"page_categorisation"] forKey:@"page_categorisation"];
                [newDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"modifieddate"] forKey:@"modifieddate"];
                [newDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
                [newDevice setValue:[commonvideo stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"path"] ]]forKey:@"clip_path"];
                [newDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"description"] forKey:@"descriptions"];
                 //   [newDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",incline] forKey:@"tabid"];
                [dataArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"clip_name"]];

                //NSLog(@"name is%@",[dict objectForKey:@"clip_name"]);

                NSError *error = nil;

                // Save the object to persistent store
                    if (![context save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                }
            NSLog(@"dataarray is%@",dataArray);
            NSLog(@"dataarray count is%lu",(unsigned long)dataArray.count);
            [[self delegate]getsyncdata:YES andDate:[serverdata objectForKey:@"datetime_value"] andtotalVideoCount:[serverdata objectForKey:@"total_clips_count"] andgetVideoCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)dataArray.count]];
        }
    }
  }];
    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

and below this there is same method syncAllClips1 with same code trying to fetch the other bunch of 50 videos. there are total 150 clips in this manner 50,50 clips gets called with these tow methods back to back

Comment: Need help i am stuck... help will be appreciated